# Browser Extension - Pass address bar URL to API

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension

So i'm looking at adapting a simple extension for myself. I browse with Safari and Chrome mainly, but occasionally test in Firefox and end up using it for a few days, so I wouldn't mind porting the idea to all three to forget about it.

Basically I want to automatically send every URL the browser visits via the Viglink REST-API. I'm going to assume this is pretty simple, but I have no idea how to get the address bar URL and send it and then return the change to the address bar URL (in essence I guess redirect everything via the API)

The API will check against its database and if no matches found just return the standard URL, if it see's a merchant it will return the affiliated link. This would ensure that i'd always get commission for my own browsing without remembering to affiliate all links via Viglink (or Skimlink) first as I often forget.

So I have a simple browser extension set up for all three browsers, but the HTML and Javascript parts are empty and I have no idea how id do what I need to do.

Here is the Viglink Rest API documentation http://support.viglink.com/entries/20646001-API-Documentation

Comment: besides the viglink api you also need to look at the documentation for chrome extensions. its not that large and should give you some ideas. there are multiple ways to do this. come back with some ideas from there and ideally a specific question about them.

Comment: Thanks Zig, could you point me in the right direction as to what you think might be the best method to do it? The most background and seamless would be best.

Comment: I mean I need a pointer, in to exactly which parts of the Chrome documentation even applies to getting the URL the browser is trying to fetch, i'm looking and I have no where to begin, about 10 things seems like it has something to do with it, but I could be wrong on all ten. So specifically what should I be reading up about to send all browser URLs to the Viglink API?

Comment: i havent done that before. i know is doable with a content script injected on all pages but i doubt that's the optimal way. look at tabs api or hooking into network requests. id have to do the same research you have pending to give a better answer

Comment: Go with a kango framework or other similar framework, you can code once and it works across all browsers even ie.

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart that sounds like a good way to go.